# In a serverless.yml file, how does one customize the default http response template?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

Looking at the documentation here https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#custom-response-templates, there doesn't seem to be much detail at all about setting up these templates.

I'm currently looking to remove the default `application/json` content-type, which is generated during creation of the handler's integration response (pictured below), and replace it with `text/html`. Is there defined syntax for how to do this hidden somewhere? Or is this level of customization not possible within the current scope of the framework?

Here is my endpoint as defined in serverless.yml

```
events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /
          integration: lambda
          request:
            region: ${env:AwsRegion}
          response:
            headers:
              Content-Type: "'text/html'"
            template: $input.path('body')
       - http:
          method: any
          path: /{proxy+}
```

Which produces the following configuration on AWS Api Gateway:
[image: Api Gateway Integration Response Mapping]

I did try modifying the specification like this, as a guess, but it threw a syntax error:

```
template: 
  text\html: $input.path('body')
```

Comment: I think for response templates the value you just put it in `template`. `template: $input.path('body')`. The type of the response is handled by the `Content-Type`. For request templates you can have different templates based on the content type, and in that case you do it like you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Make It Work

It looks like this isn't really supported by the framework, but it can be hacked together by (ab)using `statusCodes` in your serverless template.

Moving the response template to under a status code, and providing a `pattern` for that status code, accomplishes what I think you are after.  The syntax:

```
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /
          integration: lambda
          request:
            region: us-east-1
          response:
            headers:
              Content-Type: "'text/html'"
            statusCodes:
              200:
                pattern: ""
                template:
                  text/html: $input.path('body')
```

Note: Both the `pattern` and the `template` must be present.

---

### Is It Really That Bad?

That's up to you, ultimately.  I'm calling it a hack because:

- It would be much nicer to be able to supply this at the `response.template` level, rather than at `response.statusCodes.200.template`.
- Specifying one or more `statusCodes` removes the set of default lambda error regexes that you get when you don't specify any.
- It feels like working around the fact that `response.template` will only accept a string, whereas it could (should?) accept a string or an object (like it does under `statusCodes`).

---

### Fix It?

The [offending code](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/7abb23edc8dfbe5005ac716aa137330741759929/lib/plugins/aws/package/compile/events/apiGateway/lib/method/integration.js#L168), from `/lib/plugins/aws/package/compile/events/apiGateway/lib/method/integration.js`:

```
        if (http.response.template) {
          _.merge(integrationResponse.ResponseTemplates, {
            'application/json': http.response.template,
          });
        }

        if (config.template) {
          const template =
            typeof config.template === 'string'
              ? { 'application/json': config.template }
              : config.template;

          _.merge(integrationResponse.ResponseTemplates, template);
        }
```

I think for this to work under `response.template`, the code in the first `if()` would need to behave more like the code in the second `if()`.